# C++: When I change max number of elements in array, the merge sort stops working?

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, sorting

EDIT: It seems to only work if MAX / 4 = whole number...hmm I guess the rounding screws it up?

I'm playing around with this multithreaded merge sort code, but when I change MAX (size of array) to something other than 20, it no longer sorts correctly. I can't seem to understand why.

```
// CPP Program to implement merge sort using 
// multi-threading 
#include <iostream> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <time.h> 

// number of elements in array 
#define MAX 20 

// number of threads 
#define THREAD_MAX 4 

using namespace std; 

// array of size MAX 
int a[MAX]; 
int part = 0; 

// merge function for merging two parts 
void merge(int low, int mid, int high) 
{ 
    int* left = new int[mid - low + 1]; 
    int* right = new int[high - mid]; 

    // n1 is size of left part and n2 is size 
    // of right part 
    int n1 = mid - low + 1, n2 = high - mid, i, j; 

    // storing values in left part 
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
        left[i] = a[i + low]; 

    // storing values in right part 
    for (i = 0; i < n2; i++) 
        right[i] = a[i + mid + 1]; 

    int k = low; 
    i = j = 0; 

    // merge left and right in ascending order 
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) { 
        if (left[i] <= right[j]) 
            a[k++] = left[i++]; 
        else
            a[k++] = right[j++]; 
    } 

    // insert remaining values from left 
    while (i < n1) { 
        a[k++] = left[i++]; 
    } 

    // insert remaining values from right 
    while (j < n2) { 
        a[k++] = right[j++]; 
    } 
} 

// merge sort function 
void merge_sort(int low, int high) 
{ 
    // calculating mid point of array 
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2; 
    if (low < high) { 

        // calling first half 
        merge_sort(low, mid); 

        // calling second half 
        merge_sort(mid + 1, high); 

        // merging the two halves 
        merge(low, mid, high); 
    } 
} 

// thread function for multi-threading 
void* merge_sort(void* arg) 
{ 
    // which part out of 4 parts 
    int thread_part = part++; 

    // calculating low and high 
    int low = thread_part * (MAX / 4); 
    int high = (thread_part + 1) * (MAX / 4) - 1; 

    // evaluating mid point 
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2; 
    if (low < high) { 
        merge_sort(low, mid); 
        merge_sort(mid + 1, high); 
        merge(low, mid, high); 
    } 
} 

// Driver Code 
int main() 
{ 
    // generating random values in array 
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) 
        a[i] = rand() % 100; 

    // t1 and t2 for calculating time for 
    // merge sort 
    clock_t t1, t2; 

    t1 = clock(); 
    pthread_t threads[THREAD_MAX]; 

    // creating 4 threads 
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_MAX; i++) 
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, merge_sort, 
                                        (void*)NULL); 

    // joining all 4 threads 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL); 

    // merging the final 4 parts 
    merge(0, (MAX / 2 - 1) / 2, MAX / 2 - 1); 
    merge(MAX / 2, MAX/2 + (MAX-1-MAX/2)/2, MAX - 1); 
    merge(0, (MAX - 1)/2, MAX - 1); 

    t2 = clock(); 

    // displaying sorted array 
    cout << "Sorted array: "; 
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) 
        cout << a[i] << " "; 

    // time taken by merge sort in seconds 
    cout << "Time taken: " << (t2 - t1) /  
              (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl; 

    return 0;
```

It ONLY sorts correctly with an array of 20 numbers, otherwise the sorted output is incorrect. Shouldn't it be flexible enough to sort any amount of array numbers?

Comment: Try without parallelization first with four successive calls to `merge_sort(nullptr)`, it will be easier to debug. Then, after finding the problem, you can parallelize the code. And do not forget to lock access to shared memory (e.g., `parts`).

Comment: In `merge_sort(void*arg)`, be careful of the last `n%4` elements, they are left off and never sorted. And check the indices of the final merge after the join, they are wrong in some cases.